# Show that $EX^2 = 2\int_0^\infty x(1-F(x)) dx$ for $X>0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X>0$ with density $f(x)$, have distribution $F(x)$. Show that $$EX^2 = 2\int_0^\infty x(1-F(x)) dx$$

My attempt:

By definition, $F(x)=\int^{x}_{-\infty} f(u) du$. Therefore we can write $1-F(x)=\int^{\infty}_{x} f(u) du$. If we substitute this in ( in an attempt to work backwards to obtain the result) we have $$2\int_0^\infty x(1-F(x)) dx = 2\int_0^\infty (x\int^{\infty}_{x} f(u) du) dx$$ From here I have attempted to make this equal to $\int_0^\infty x^2f(x) dx$ but with no success. I figure somehow I am supposed to show that $$\int^{\infty}_{x} f(u) du = \frac{xf(x)}{2}$$ I have a feeling this is fairly simple but I'm just missing something obvious. Please help!

Comment: 13 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last step, change the order the integration to get

\begin{equation}
2 \int_0^\infty x \int_x^\infty f(u)\, du\, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^u 2xf(u)\, dx\, du = \int_0^\infty u^2\, f(u)\, du = EX^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: *order change* allowed only if we know that these integrals exist, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3):

The formula does not require the existence of a density and follows by integrating with respect to $P$ the leftmost and rightmost parts of the pointwise identity, obvious when $X\geqslant0$ almost surely, $$X^2=\int_0^X2x\,\mathrm dx=2\int_0^\infty x\,\mathbf 1_{X\gt x}\,\mathrm dx,$$ using the relation, valid for every $x$, $$P(X\gt x)=1-F(x).$$

Comment: Can we say that this identity holds even if the $EX^2$ does not exist? (all the above proof given so far rely on Fubini which requires the existence of $EX^2$) The question does not state anything along the line of existence.

Comment: The proof in my answer relies on Tonelli, not Fubini, and Tonelli holds for every nonnegative (measurable) functions, whether they are integrable or not. Hence yes "we can say that this identity holds" whether $E(X^2)$ is finite or infinite since this is what my answer shows.

Comment: Awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$2\int_0^ax(1-F(x))dx = \int_0^a (1-F(x)) d\left(x^2 \right) = \int_0^a d \left(x^2 \left(1-F(x) \right) \right) + \int_0^a x^2 dF(x)$$
Hence,
$$2\int_0^ax(1-F(x))dx = a^2 \left(1-F(a) \right) + \int_0^a x^2 dF(x)$$
Taking the limit as $a \to \infty$, we obtain what we want.

Comment: You need to assume that $Pr(X>t)\sim t^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha>2$. This is not given ...